# Why is the PHP function "implode" returning the string "array"?

Tags: php, arrays

I am calling the following function:

```
function buildInStmt($array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $in = implode(',', $array);
    } else $in = "'" . $array . "'";
    var_dump("in=" . $in); 
    var_dump("$array=" . $array); 
    return $in;
}

...

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["form-type"]) || empty($_REQUEST["form-type"])) {
        throw new Exception('You must select a form type.');       
    }
    $forms = buildInStmt(array($_REQUEST["form-type"]));
```

The var_dumps from the function are returning:

string 'in=Array' (length=8)

string 'Array=Array' (length=11)

string 'in=Array' (length=8)

string 'Array=Array' (length=11)

string 'in=1' (length=4)

string 'Array=Array' (length=11)

The var_dump(array($_REQUEST["form-type"])); from the call returns:

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)

Why isn't implode returning a comma delimited string?

Iff you elect to downvote this question, please explain the reason so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Because you have an array of arrays, or so it seems.

Comment: Thanks, Francisco. I am passing an array  from ajax. Works now.

Comment: Perfect, glad to know it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array (size=1) 0 => array (size=2) 0 => string '4' (length=1) 1 => string '7' (length=1)
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
$var = [
  0 => [
    0 => '4',
    1 => '8'
  ]
]
```

So it seems that you have an array of arrays. Try not adding an unneeded array from your code:

```
buildInStmt($_REQUEST["form-type"])
```